# Does CouchDB support file diffs on attachments when replicating?

Tags: couchdb

Say I create an attachment on one Couch server and replicate it to another server. Now both servers have the same attachment.

If I then update the attachment on one server and replicate to the other, will Couch perform a file diff and only transfer the differences? Or does it transfer the entire attachment?

If it can perform diffs, but not by default, how can I configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It transfer the entire attachment.